# Newly added property is not visible on Document class in ACCE Filenet p8

Tags: filenet-p8

I am not able to see the newly added property under Document class to add in ACCE Filenet p8

Comment: Please consider adding some more details to the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new property under any document class involves couple of steps

1. First you need to create a property template if it's not done already and save it.
2. Then navigate to the document class to which you want to add the property and click on "Property Definitions" tab
3. Now click on "Add" and look for the property that you just added and select it.
4. Click on "Save"

Now the property is available under your document class.